# CakePHP 4 Authentication

Tags: authentication, cakephp-4.x

How can I update the users record at login? I have a "last login date" field that I would like to update each time a user logs in. Trying to save within the login action has been unsuccessful. I am using CakePHP 4, my login action follows:

```
public function login()
    {
        $this->request->allowMethod(['get', 'post']);
        $result = $this->Authentication->getResult();
        // regardless of POST or GET, redirect if user is logged in
        if ($result->isValid()) {
            // redirect to /articles after login success
            $redirect = $this->request->getQuery('redirect', [
                'controller' => 'Pages',
                //'action' => 'index',
            ]);
            /*
             * Update users last login
             */
            $usersTable = $this->getTableLocator()->get('Users');
            $userId = $this->Auth->user('id');
            $user = $usersTable->get($userId);
            $user->last_login = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $usersTable->save($user);
            /*
             * End update
             */
            return $this->redirect($redirect);
        }
        // display error if user submitted and authentication failed
        if ($this->request->is('post') && !$result->isValid()) {
            $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password'));
        }
    }
```

The error is: "Call to a member function user() on null". The code identified is: `$userId = $this->Auth->user('id');`
Appreciate any help!

Comment: What part of this isn't working?

Comment: The error is:
```Call to a member function user() on null```
The highlighted code is:
```$userId = $this->Auth->user('id');```

Comment: Ah, right. That's presumably code you found somewhere, but it's using the old Auth component, not the new plugin. You can use `$this->Authentication->getIdentity()` now to get the details of the logged-in user.

Comment: That's it. Shortcuts often aren't, yet they can be tempting.
Thanks Greg!